# CkEditor5 textarea required doesn't work if I want to submit a not empty field

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, ckeditor, ckeditor5

My problem is that i want to set a textarea tag on required. But i soon as I include the CKEditor it wont work. I mean like, the Textarea is not empty put if I submit my form, a error message appiers that the textarea is empty.And if i press submit again it will work. What do I have to do, to set this field required.

I use HTML, Coldfusion and JS. Coldfusion doesnt matter at the moment.

```js
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#CKTextfeldDU'), {
    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<cftextarea id="CKTextfeldDU" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" name="DBeschreibungDU" required="yes"></cftextarea>
```

Comment: Just a small comment. CKEditor is a JavaScript/HTML editor. cftextarea is CFML and not HTML. CFML will just generate some html code on the server side for you. Thus, you can't manipulate the 'requried' attribute of cftextarea. You need to manipulate the generated HTML code.. I suggest using plain HTML without CFML instead and then manipulate the HTML dom with jquery/JavaScript.

Comment: still doesnt work. the Submit button is like disabled but it isn't disabled